# jetty-logging.properties not applying to servlet

Tags: java, maven, jetty, slf4j, jetty-9

I inherited a jetty project with no logging configuration defined, but debugging logs seem to be enabled somehow anyway. When I try to add a `src/main/resources/jetty-logging.properties` file with this configuration, nothing seems to change.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=INFO
ca.uhn.fhir.context.LEVEL=INFO //3rd party library causing DEBUG logs
```

When I start the service locally using the maven plugin for jetty
`mvn -Djetty.http.port=8080 jetty:run`

I can see logs which indicate a default jetty logging package of org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog

```
[INFO] Logging initialized @11194ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = ${LocalPath}\eclipse-workspace\cql-execution-service\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:///${LocalPath}/cql-execution-service/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = ${LocalPath}\src\main\webapp
[INFO] jetty-9.4.7.v20170914
[INFO] Scanning elapsed time=15583ms
[INFO] DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
[INFO] No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
[INFO] Scavenging every 660000ms
[INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@2b148329{/,file:///${LocalPath}/cql-execution-service/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:///${LocalPath}/cql-execution-service/src/main/webapp/}
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@69f69078{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] Started @32649ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

This is my web.xml file:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

  <display-name>CqlExecSvc</display-name>

  <filter>
   <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
  </filter> 
  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>CqlEngine</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
     <param-value>org.opencds.cqf.cql.execution</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>CqlEngine</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

However, in my logs, I can see a lot of debugging statements from the 3rd party package, and I cannot find any other logging configuration. Any ideas as to what to check for next?

Answer (score 1):

In Jetty 9.x the configuration ...

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
```

Will use the built-in logger for `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger` based logging events and emit them to `System.err` (aka `STDERR` / Standard Error)

This only looks for logging events from the Jetty specific logger facade, nothing else.

If you want something more complex you'll have to setup something like slf4j and logback correctly to capture the logging events from everywhere (eg: `java.util.logging`, `log4j`, `slf4j`, `commons-logging`, etc) and route them to your specific logback appender.

In Jetty 10+ the Jetty specific Logging Facade has been dropped in favor of slf4j.  All logging is done via that interface, which gives you immense levels of configuration across a wide variety of logging implementations.